# Which one is more efficient? Caching method call result used in for loop

Tags: java, performance

The difference is probably miniscule or doesn't exist, but which one is more efficient and why?

```
int nItems = param.getItemList().size();
for (...) {
    if (nitems == 1) doSomething();
}
```

or

```
for (...) {
    if (param.getItemList().size() == 1) doSomething();
}
```

Comment: *"which one is more efficient"*  1) What happened when you tested it? 2) What do you mean by 'efficient'?

Answer (score 8):

In theory the first one will be faster (have you profiled it? you should!), because it pulls a frequently used method call outside of the loop. However, given enough time the JIT compiler might optimize/inline the method call making both solutions indistinguishable in terms of performance.

Such micro-micro-optimizations are not worth the effort, better aim for the solution that it's clearer and simpler to understand. Which IMHO happens to be the first one.

Answer (score 1):

It is more efficient to make the method call outside the loop.  Sometimes it may even matter.  The one circumstance under which the second approach might be more efficient is if the conditions of the `for` loop resulted in the loop being skipped entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The first is more efficient because the method need not be invoked several times.  However, as both `getItemList()` and `size()` seem to be accessors, the difference will be miniscule.

Answer (score 0):

The first one, because you don't need to make the two calls for every iteration of the loop